# Even street orphans speak in riddles nowadays

Tags: rhyme, pattern, knowledge

> How do you do, my name's Gavroche,
>   whispering words of wisdom, see?
>   Bucharest coins are nothing posh,
>   neither is neighbouring currency.
>   This is the man that wrote the song "Charmaine",
>   this is a man who fights *(???)*.
>   In Spanish courts this word is often named.
>   What's in the blank space, can you tell?

Looking for the name of a fictional character.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a man who fights ...

> ... **Kal-El**.
>
>  Each line in the verse describes a word that begins with **Le–** and ends in one of the letters from **s** to **y**, so the word at the blank must be **Lex**. Lex Luthor is a supervillain who fights Superman. Superman was born on Krypton as Kal-El, and that rhymes with "tell". I've got all tags covered, I hope. `:)`

How do you do, my name's Gavroche,

> [Gavroche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gavroche) is the titular street orphan in Victor Hugo's **Les** Misérables.

whispering words of wisdom, see?

> [***Let** it be.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_It_Be_(song))

Bucharest coins are nothing posh,

> The [currency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies) of Romania is the Romanian **Leu**.

neither is neighbouring currency.

> The [currency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies) of Bulgaria is the Bulgarian **Lev**.

This is the man that wrote the song "Charmaine",

> **Lew** Pollack and Ernö Rapée [wrote that song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charmaine_(song)) in 1926.

this is a man who fights (???).

> [**Lex** Luthor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_Luthor) is a supervillain and Superman's enemy.

In Spanish courts this word is often named.

> **Ley** is Spanish for law.

Comment: +1 from Krypton! Though my Krypton means hidden though ;)